# sorl.thumbnail and s3 are adding port 80 to the url and encoding it also even with |safe

Tags: django, templates, amazon-s3, sorl-thumbnail

I have the sorl.thumbnail template tag on my site but the template always renders it out like this (it's the img tag that is messing up):

```
<li>
    <a href="myamazonurl/screenshots/tl-opening.jpg">
        <img src="myamazonurl:80/cache%2F53%2Ff4%2F53f489f64c64ee345301c55b9f8ed0af.jpg">
    </a>
</li>
```

From what I can see the image saved in the db has the correct path and my media url is also correct since the link to the image is 100% ok. Here is my template code:

```
{% load thumbnail %}
{% for galleryImage in app.album.screenshots.all %}

{% thumbnail galleryImage.image "92x92" crop="center" colorspace="GRAY" as im %}
<li>
     <a href="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ galleryImage.image }}">
         <img src="{{ im.url|safe }}">
     </a>
 </li>
 {% endthumbnail %}
 {% endfor %}
```

I have tried googleing/stacking for everything, and I have no idea an more. I have no idea where the port is coming from or where to configure it. I need pointing in the right direction by wiser people :)

Please let me know if you need to know more.

P.S the galleryImage.image is just a normal image field

Comment: What file storage backend are you using?